# How to create a dummy massless body in Drake?

Tags: drake

I am trying to create a massless dummy body in Drake by `dummy_body = RigidBody()` similar to the [test file](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/attic/multibody/test/rigid_body_tree_test.py#L486). But it seems that `SpatialInertia` must be passed into the [constructor](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/tree/rigid_body.cc). Is there a standard way to make a massless body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way that the urdf parser initialized the spatial inertia if there is not inertial element:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/0ab38013ef031f9f48d30acf02e05bb136f20c5f/multibody/parsing/detail_urdf_parser.cc#L113

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason to add a massless body instead of a frame?

Comment: It’s our recommended work-around until we offer a planar joint — two prismatic joints followed by a revolute joint, with massless bodies in between.